# Regex: Matching outer substring

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I haven't been able to find an example of this.
Given a string that contains a substring, I want to select just the outer string.

Example:

```
NumberLong("98237234234")
```

I want to select NumberLong("") and not the number inside the quotes. This way, I can do a find and replace inside IntelliJ to get rid of that and keep the number inside.

My current regex selects the whole thing:

```
(NumberLong\(")\d*("\))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're intention is to keep the middle, place a group around it and refer to it in the replacement.

```
Find: NumberLong\("(\d+)"\)
Replace: $1
```